# Don't know how to convert "Recipe4" into edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.Recipe

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, cucumber

My feature file scenario is this:

```
When Recipe4 is added to the recipe book
```

And the corresponding StepDef is this :

```
@When("^(.*) is added to the recipe book$")
public void addRecipeTest(Recipe recipe) throws RecipeException {
    //Set up 
            
            recipe = new Recipe();
            recipe.setName("Hot Chocolate");
            recipe.setAmtChocolate("4");
            recipe.setAmtCoffee("0");
            recipe.setAmtMilk("1");
            recipe.setAmtSugar("1");
            recipe.setPrice("65");
        
            assertEquals(true,coffeeMaker.addRecipe(recipe));
            assertEquals(coffeeMakerMain.getMode(),Mode.WAITING);
            System.out.println("Recipe is added");
}
```

I am trying to see if i can get my code to accept the regular expression as a (Recipe)class object but I am getting this error:

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Don't know how to convert "Recipe4" into edu.ncsu.csc326.coffeemaker.Recipe.
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I convert string to pojo

```
When I add  user by passing <userInfo> to pojo class from scenario outline

Examples:
|userInfo|
        |TestFirstName,TestLastName|
```

Converter is this

```
@ParameterType(".*?")
          public addUserPojo defineStringToPojo(String adduser) {
            List<String> usr = Arrays.asList(adduser.split(","));
           return  new addUserPojo(usr.get(0),usr.get(1));
          }
```

step Definition is

```
@When("I add  user by passing {defineStringToPojo} to pojo class from scenario outline")
        public void AddUserWithPOJOScOut( addUserPojo adduser) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
           
             
           System.out.println("firstname..."+adduser.getFirstName());
           System.out.println("LastName..."+adduser.getLastName());

}
```

pojo is this

```
public class addUserPojo {
    
    private String FirstName;
  private  String LastName;

  
    public addUserPojo(String fname, String lname){
        this.FirstName = fname;
         this.LastName=lname;
                 
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
         return LastName;
    }

}
```

As you are not using scenario outline , you dont have to do `split` , just use string and it should work